# Content Editor Web Part Does Not Allow Edits Once Added Via Designer

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, page-layout, content-editor-web-part

I have created a page layout in SharePoint Designer 2010 and I added the content editor webpart so that users could add content in a specific part on the page. When i saved and published my page layout and created a new page, I could see the webpart but when the page was in edit mode, I could not edit it. It does not even show the "Click here to edit this web part" text. All i see is a box.

Is there a setting I am supposed to change within Designer? Am i trying to use this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the content editor web part to work, you must first create a web part zone and place it on the page. Then you can add web parts to that section. Now when i go to the page in edit mode, i am able to add content and save.

Answer (score 0):

In edit mode you should click on the box. That will bring up the ribbon tools for text editing.

Another alternative to your approach is by using `RichHtmlField` instead of content editor

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField InputFieldLabel="centercontentbox" FieldName="6946f02c-c941-452e-be99-14126eb266ef" runat="server"></PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField>
```

Comment: When i am in edit mode on my webpage the box is not clickable. I just tried adding the RichHTMLField code you supplied as well. That does not render on my webpage. It shows up as blank. I don't even see a border around the section. Could it be the content type that I created the page layout from?

Comment: Try to follow this articles http://sprider.org/2012/10/12/how-to-create-wiki-custom-page-layout-rich-text-control-inside-your-page-layout/

Comment: Hm, I have followed these steps already. This article mentions "All it needs now is RTE or edit mode css included within the master page.". Is it saying that I need to add some extra code to make my richtext field show up?